# Selenium webdriver using facebook php library - implicit wait or wait for element present?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test a file upload using the facebook php library for webdriver, and it appears that the upload is working because the source code shows the 'loading' notification, but I can't seem to get the test to wait for the file to upload before proceeding to the next step.  I can't find any reference to either an implicit wait (not ideal, but would probably do the trick) or a wait for element present in any documentation or discussion among people using this library.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do an implicit wait:

```
$this->_session->timeouts()->implicit_wait(3000); // 1 sec = 1000
```